# How to solve InvokeHTTP error?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, apache-nifi

Since I have try to get data from HTTPS.

For that i have configured "GetHTTP" processor with **"StandardSSLContextService"**.

**i have Created JKS using KeyTool and imported Security certificate(.CER) file for website into it.**

i can able get data from "HTTPS" URL using "GetHTTP" but it not worked in "InvokeHTTP".

I have used GetHTTP for download one file from Server.But i need to download 100 files from Server using Loop.In that case i should not drag the "GetHTTP" processor for 100 files.

That's why i have find **loop** in NiFi with the InvokeHttp to download 100 files by index 1 to 100 with single processor.

In InvokeHTTP shows following exception but it runs in GetHTTP well.

`ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP InvokeHTTP[id=4aa3eb07-8dce-4037-867b-2d36b0b6fab8] Routing to Failure due to exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available`

But those changes worked in GetHTTP.

Can anyone guide me solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to do authentication and authorization via x509 certificates, or just trying to do simple HTTPS with the server?  Have you tried InvokeTTP without a StandardSSLContextService?

Comment: James,I just trying to do simple HTTPS with server.And my website starts with "HTTPS://myurl.domain".So use Invoke HTTP  with StandardSSLContextService only

Comment: In my experiment, I did not need a StandardSSLContextService to query from an HTTPS endpoint with InvokeHTTP.  Have you tried InvokeHTTP without the service?

Comment: Yes james i have tried InvokeHTTP without Service it leads 404 not Found Error.And one more thing if i create "TrustStore" for StandardSSLContext Service then it worked.But it not worked in "KeyStore".